# compare ranges and populate values in VBA Macro

Tags: excel, compare, range, populate

I am trying to write a macro to compare two ranges, Rng1 and Rng2 in excel.  Rng1, ("f2:f15"), contains target numbers which are being used.  Rng2, ("a2:a91"), contains the numbers for all possible targets.  The three columns to the right of Rng2, ("b2:b91"), ("c2:c91"), and ("d2:d91"), contain the x, y, and z coordinate values associated with each target number.  What I would like this macro to do is to populate the 3 columns to the right of Rng1, ("g2:g15"), ("h2:h15"), and ("i2:i15") with the coordinate values of the target number found in Rng1. The following code I have written is retuning "Run time error '13', type mismatch".

```
Sub macro()
Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Cell1 As Range, Cell2 As Range
Set Rng1 = Range("f2:f15")
Set Rng2 = Range("a2:a91")
For i = 1 To Rng1
    For j = 1 To Rng2
        For Each Cell1 In Rng1(i)
            For Each Cell2 In Rng1(j)
               If Cell1.Value = Cell2.Value Then
                'cell1.Offset(0, 1) = cell2.Offset(0, 1)
                'cell1.Offset(0, 1) = cell2.Offset(0, 1)
                'cell1.Offset(0, 1) = cell2.Offset(0, 1)
                Cells(2 + i, 7) = Cells(2 + j, 2)
                Cells(2 + i, 8) = Cells(2 + j, 3)
                Cells(2 + i, 9) = Cells(2 + j, 4)
             End If
          Next Cell2
       Next Cell1
     Next j
  Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Write out, in words, exactly what you are trying to accomplish with `For I = 1 to Rng1` statement.  And how many Cells would you expect to be in `Rng1(1)`?

Comment: I am trying to use I = 1 to Rng1 as a counter to keep track of the value in Rng1, as I am trying to use j as a counter to keep track of values in Rng2.  I am not a very experienced coder and may be doing this very incorrectly.  Thanks!

Comment: But Rng1 is a multicell range object.  So a loop that runs from 1 to ?? is not meaningful.  That's why you get the type mismatch error.  Look at VBA Help for `For ...Next` loops.  And then, later on, you have `For each cell in Rng1(i)`.  If I = 1, then Rng1(I) would be the first cell in that range.  Again, Each cell in Rng1(I) would be only one cell.  You probably could eliminate completely the `I` and `j` loops, and still cycle through each cell in the ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description I think this is what you want

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Cell1 As Range
    Dim i As Variant
    Set Rng1 = Range("f2:f15")
    Set Rng2 = Range("a2:a91")

    '  Loop over the cells you want to add data for
    For Each Cell1 In Rng1
        ' locate current value in range 2
        i = Application.Match(Cell1.Value, Rng2, 0)
        If Not IsError(i) Then
            ' if found copy offset data
            Cell1.Offset(0, 1) = Rng2.Cells(i, 2)
            Cell1.Offset(0, 2) = Rng2.Cells(i, 3)
            Cell1.Offset(0, 3) = Rng2.Cells(i, 4)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```